# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 URLBlocked>

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, urllib, http-status-code-403

i am trying to scrap weather and pollution data from openweathermap through python,
i am using urllib and the URL i try to access is HTTPS, here is my code :

```
api_key = self.dict_config["api_key"]
urlweather = self.dict_config["weather_url"] % (lat, lon, dt, api_key)
request=urllib.request.Request(urlweather)
request.add_header('client_id','xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
request.add_header('client_secret','xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/6.0')
proxy='xxxxxxxxxxxxx:8080'
request.set_proxy(proxy, 'https')
with urllib.request.urlopen(request, context=self.gcontext) as response:
     weather = response.read().decode()
     return weather
```

but with this code i have a `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 URLBlocked>`
i've tried a to do the same but with `urllib.request.opener` not using a proxy try to pass my headers in an other way, not using user agent etc.. but nothing works.

interesting point : when i run this shell command on the same server it works :

```
curl -k --location --request GET 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/owm/v1/data/2.5/onecall/timemachine?lat=51.2&lon=6.4&dt=1667390504&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&units=metric' --header 'client_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' --header 'client_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

(i've obviously tested if my URL was correct when building it in the code)

So if you have any ideas please let me know !

Comment: did you try to work with `requests` module instead of `urllib`?

Comment: no because my company decided to use this lib in the rest of the code and i don't want to refacto the whole thing

Comment: it can be a problem with your proxy settings, did you try to run your code without adding the proxy parameter?

Comment: yep didn't worked either